# How to access a widget/id from a class using popup widget(Button) in KIvy

Tags: python, class, popup, kivy, screen

I am having problem accessing the widget id from a class ( Here `SecondWindow` ). This class have a Button with id `name_btn` which triggers a popup which have a `TextInput` widget in it with id `my_field`. I want to change the `text` of the Button in `SecondWindow` to whatever the user writes in the textinput... How can i do that.

I Tried accessing the button's text using self.parent.ids.name_btn.text but it gives me an error stating `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'`.
Any help is apperciated my codes are below>>

main.py

```
import kivy
import kivymd
kivy.require('1.10.1')
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager , Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


class Main(Screen):
    pass

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    name_btn = ObjectProperty(None)
    def pop_(self):
        pop_up()


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass  

class time_intrvl(FloatLayout): 
    
    my_field = ObjectProperty(None)
    
    def yeah(self):
        self.parent.ids.name_btn.text = self.my_field.text


class ExamPortal(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        kv = Builder.load_file('my.kv')        
        return kv
        
def pop_up():
    pop_window = time_intrvl()
    PopUpWindow = Popup(title = 'Enter Time' ,content = pop_window,size_hint = (0.5,0.3))
    PopUpWindow.open()         
            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ExamPortal().run()
```

and my.kv

```
        
<time_intrvl>:

    my_field : my_field

    TextInput:
        id : my_field
        multiline : False
        pos_hint : {'x':0.1 , 'top': 0.74}
        size_hint : None,None
        size : 200,60
        font_size : 26
        

        
    Button:
        size_hint : None , None
        text : 'Done'
        size : 80,26
        font_size : 14    
        pos_hint : {'x':0.8,'top':0.18}
        on_release:
            root.yeah()
            
WindowManager:
    Main:
    SecondWindow:
              
<Main>:
    name : 'main'
    GridLayout:
        cols : 1
        Button:
            
            text : 'Go to SecondWindow'
            on_release:
                app.root.current = 'sec_wind'
<SecondWindow>
    name : 'sec_wind'
    name_btn : name_btn
    
    GridLayout:
        cols : 1
        Button:
            id : name_btn
            text:'Enter Text'
            on_release:
                root.pop_()
```

`

Answer (score 0):

A few small changes to get what you want working. Modify the `pop_up()` to return the `PopUpWindow` so that it can be available to be closed:

```
def pop_up():
    pop_window = time_intrvl()
    PopUpWindow = Popup(title = 'Enter Time' ,content = pop_window,size_hint = (0.5,0.3))
    PopUpWindow.open()
    return PopUpWindow
```

Then modify `SecondWindow` to keep a reference to the `PopUpWindow`:

```
class SecondWindow(Screen):
    name_btn = ObjectProperty(None)
    def pop_(self):
        self.popup = pop_up()
```

And, finally, modify `time_intrvl` to modify the Button text and dismiss the `PopUpWindow`:

```
class time_intrvl(FloatLayout):

    my_field = ObjectProperty(None)

    def yeah(self):
        second_window = MDApp.get_running_app().root.get_screen('sec_wind')
        second_window.name_btn.text = self.my_field.text
        second_window.popup.dismiss()
```

The above code uses `MDApp.get_running_app()` to get a reference to the `App`, then gets the `root` of the `App`, which is the `WindowManager`. Then it uses the `get_screen()` method to get a reference to the `SecondWindow`. With that reference we can then change the Button text and dismiss the `PopUpWindow`.

Comment: thanks brother, howevere I can't get how WindowManager became the root of the app.

Comment: and brother on more doubt how is it possible that we are directly accessing the variable which is inside a function like we didn't made that variable a global variable . here i am referring to `self.popup` which is in `pop_` in SecondWindow

Comment: The `WindowManager` is set to root by the `kv` file where the `WindowManager` rule appears as a root rue without surrounding `<>`.

Comment: The `self.popup` is not a global variable, but it is an instance variable of the `SecondWindow`, which allows it to be accessed using the `self.` construct.

Comment: Brother sry to disturb but one doubt more how can I access the widgets here `TextInput <my_field>` that belongs to popup and not a screen . I want to access the textinput from SecondWndow screen class

Comment: You need to post that as a new question.